# Java Regular Expression for RIC code

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression in Java that will determine if a string is of a valid market data format (RIC).  The acceptable instrument codes are composed of a root (one to four characters – A through Z), followed by a period sign, then a one- or two-character (A through Z) code.

Comment: Note that this will *not* match all RICs, just a small subset of RICs that OP apparently cares about.

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
[A-Z]{1,4}\.[A-Z]{1,2}
```

this Java focused page may help http://www.shiffman.net/teaching/a2z/regex/

Comment: Almost exactly what I had :) Just need to add the ^/$ anchors so it doesn't validate A.B.C.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[A-Z]{1,4}\.[A-Z]{1,2}$/
```

Sample and tests can be found at http://refiddle.co/10o

Answer (score 0):

Your specific use-case and the above answers lack support for option symbols, which are also valid RIC codes, nor do they take into account compound "exchange" markers, or indices, such as ".SPSUPX" for S&P 1500.

For example, while the other answers will identify "IBM.N", it won't identify "SPXWF162320000.U", which is a weekly SPX option.

The following regex will cover both cases, and will split it up into it's constituent parts. Do note that "expiryMonth" is a single character flag representing the month, type (whether CALL or PUT) as well as the denomination of the strike price.

For example an "A" means January, CALL, strike price < 1000 (so strike price is represented in 10 cents. By comparison a "n" (explicitly lower-case) means February, PUT, strike price > 1000 (so strike price is represented in cents).

```
Pattern.compile("^(?<symbol>\\w+?)(?:(?<expiryMonth>[a-xA-X])(?<expiryDay>\\d{2})(?<expiryYear>\\d{2})(?<strikePrice>\\d+))?\\.(?<exchange>.+)$");
```